# utf-8に変換できないshift-jisの文字（環境依存文字）を、個別に変換する方法

Tags: python, python3

文字コードがshift-jisのバイトデータを、utf-8に変換したいのですが、
変換できない文字が含まれており、どのように変換すればよいか分かりませんでした。
例えば外字の「①」は、以下のようにすることで「(1)」に変換することができましたが、
「(1)」ではなく、utf-8の「①」に変換するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
byte_date = b'abc\x82\xa0\x82\xa2\x82\xa4\x87\x40'  # ← shift_jisの「abcあいう①」
byte_date = byte_date.replace(b'\x87\x40', b'(1)')  # \x87\x40は、shift_jisの①
text = byte_date.decode(encoding='shift_jis', errors='replace')  # errors='replace'は不要？
print(text)
```

以下は、上記コードを実行した結果です。

```
abcあいう(1)
```

以下のように変換されることを期待しています。

```
abcあいう①
```

[追記]
以下の方法で、期待どおりの結果がえられました。

```
byte_date = b'abc\x82\xa0\x82\xa2\x82\xa4\x87\x40'  # ← shift_jisの「abcあいう①」
text = byte_date.decode(encoding='cp932')
print(text)
```

Comment: `text = byte_date.decode(encoding='cp932')`

Comment: こちらが参考記事ですね。[Python♪Windowsの「Shift JIS」の落とし穴](https://snowtree-injune.com/2020/05/15/codec-py003/), [Windows の文字コードは Python では cp932](https://criticabug.hatenablog.com/entry/python-cp932) それからこの質問の場合「外字」という表現でも間違いでは無いのですが、[機種依存文字 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A9%9F%E7%A8%AE%E4%BE%9D%E5%AD%98%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97)(や「環境依存文字」)の方がより理解されやすいと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。text = byte_date.decode(encoding='cp932')で期待した結果が得られました。環境依存文字という用語を利用するようにします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問の内容は、encodingをcp932にすれば解決しますが、「utf-8に変換できないshift-jisの文字（環境依存文字）を、個別に変換する方法」(質問文の例のように「(1)」にするなど)としては、`codecs.register_error`で自前のエラーハンドラを登録して処理する方法もあります。

- [Python標準ライブラリ - codecs](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error)
- [[python] やむを得ない事情で utf-8 の文字集合からなる日本語を sjis エンコードしなければならない場合のワークアラウンド](https://zenn.dev/hassaku63/articles/f7ca587b86398c)

```py
# coding: utf-8

import codecs

byte_date = b'abc\x82\xa0\x82\xa2\x82\xa4\x87\x40'  # ← shift_jisの「abcあいう①」
def decode_error(exc):
    encoding, text, start, end, msg = exc.args
    if text[start:start+2] == b'\x87\x40':
        return '(1)', start + 2
    raise exc
codecs.register_error('my_error', decode_error)
text = byte_date.decode(encoding='shift_jis', errors='my_error')
print(text)
```